# Kendo/JQuery searchbox doesn't search through `ICollection`?

Tags: c#, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid, and in the `.ToolBar` I have a search box that filters the grid based on what is typed in and overall, it is working fine.

The issue is that it is not reading/searching through particular columns (Maker & Associated) which involve the use of `ICollection`. I have tried a few things but I can not figure out how to write the search correctly for these columns.

I'll note that the `Maker` & `Associated` columns themselves are being populated correctly and that each of the columns' own filters also work correctly

First, this is a stripped down example of how the columns and the search box are created in the `Index.cshtml`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("gridWF")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        column.Bound (p1 => p1.Id.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).InputWidth(90))).Width(150);
        column.Bound (p1 => p1.Name.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).InputWidth(90))).Width(150);
        column.Bound (p1 => p1.Item.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).InputWidth(90))).Width(150);
        column.Bound (p1 => p1.Maker.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).InputWidth(90))).Width(150);
        column.Bound (p1 => p1.Associated.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(true).InputWidth(90))).Width(150);
    }
.Pageable()
.ColumnMenu()
.ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template(@<text><input class='k-textbox' value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value=='Search...') this.value='';" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Search...':this.value;" id='searchbox'/></text>)
.DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
  .PageSize(15)
  .ServerOperation(false)
  .Read(r => r.Action("Read", "Workflows").Data("addSearch"))
  )  

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addSearch() {
        return { searchbox: $('#searchbox').val() };
    }
    $('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
        $('#gridWF').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    });
</script>
```

Search section of controller

```
private IEnumerable<WorkflowViewModel> GetData(string searchbox = "")
        {
        var number = 0;
        int.TryParse (searchbox, out number);
        var result = (from w in Repo.GetWF()
                      where w.Id == number ||
                            w.Name.ToLower ().Contains (searchbox.ToLower ()) ||
//Failed attempt            w.UserRoles.Where (ur => ur.Role.Name.ToLower ().Contains (searchbox.ToLower())) != null || 
//Failed attempt            w.UserRoles.Where (ur => ur.Role != null && wr.Role.Name.ToLower().Equals ("maker", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select (wr => wr.UserName).FirstOrDefault ().Contains (searchbox.ToLower()) ||
                            w.ImportProduct.Item.Name.ToLower ().Contains (searchbox.ToLower ()) ||
                            searchbox == ""
                     select new ViewModel (w, User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
        return result;
        }
```

Here is the applicable code in `ViewModel.cs`

```
public class ViewModel

  public ViewModel(Workflow workflow, string userName = null)
    {
    Id = workflow.Id;  
    Name = workflow.Name;  
    Item= workflow.ImportProduct.Item.Name  
    Maker= Workflow.GetByRoles(workflow, "maker");  
    Associated= Workflow.GetByRoles(workflow, "associated");  
    }
```

`Workflow.cs`

```
public class Workflow
    {
    public Workflow()
        {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id
            {
            get;
            set;
            }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="*")]
        [Display(Name="Name")]
        public string Name
            {
            get;
            set;
            }

        [Required]
        public int ImportId
            {
            get;
            set;
            }


        [ForeignKey("ImportId")]
        public virtual Product ImportProduct 
            {
            get;
            set;
            }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles 
        {
        get;
        set;
        }

    public static string GetByRoles (Workflow workflow, string role)
        {
        string userString = "";
        if(workflow.UserRoles != null)
            {
            var query = from ur in workflow.UserRoles
            where ur.Role.Name.ToLower() == role.ToLower()
            select ur.User.DisplayName;

            foreach(string user in query.ToList()
            {
            usersString += user + ",";
            }
            usersString = usersString.Trim(' ');
            usersString = usersString.Trim(',');
            }
        return usersString;
        }
```

If I left something out, or if I was unclear at any point, please comment and I will do my best to clarify.

Thank you

**Update:**
I found a slight workaround for the search box which successfully searches through the columns.

```
//$('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
//    $('#gridWF').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
//});
$('#searchbox').keyup(function () {
    var q = $("#searchbox").val();
    var int = parseInt(q); 
    var grid = $("#gridWF").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.filter({
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
              { field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: int},
              { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: q},
              { field: "Item", operator: "contains", value: q},
              { field: "Maker", operator: "contains", value: q },
              { field: "Associated", operator: "contains", value: q }
            ]
        }
    });
```

However, this code doesn't behave as I need it to.  This types into all of the filter boxes at the top of each row which is not acceptable; I want any previous filtering using the individual filters to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
The line I needed in my `Controller.cs` was:

```
`w.UserRoles.Where (ur => ur.Role.Name.ToLower ().Contains ("maker")).Any (ur => ur.User.Name.ToLower ().Contains (searchbox.ToLower ())) ||`
```

The problem with my failed attempts was that `.Select` is a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>` which the `||` operator doesn't work with.  The `.Any` solves this because it determines if any element satisfies the condition.